# Ingress address

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, kind

I have a question about applying the ingress resource below: the address of the ingress in localhost. if I want to call the ingress address from within a pod it will not work. is there a way to get an absolute address? Thanks

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: vault-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
 rules:
  - HTTP:
     paths:
     - path: /v1/*
       backend:
        serviceName: vault
        servicePort: 8200
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on `absolute address`? What is your end goal? So I can try to answer correctly.

Comment: I eneded using nodeport intead of ingress. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> if I want to call the ingress address from within a pod it will not work

If your cluster has a **default** Ingress controller setup, you can obtain the address via `kubectl get ing`. If your cluster doesn't have a default Ingress controller setup, there will be no Ingress address available for you.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what is default ingress controller setup and how to define it? Thanks I have ingress-nginx controller installed.

Comment: If your cluster has an ingress controller annotated with `ingressclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class`, the spec in your question will be automatically handled by this controller. If you are not sure, add this annotation to your spec in the question: `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx`. This will direct ingress-nginx to handle your ingress request.